# Add column by reference on rolling join

Tags: r, data.table

The main problem is described in the question title. Going straight to the example below.

I have two datasets:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(date = as.Date("2015-06-28")+c(0L,3L,5L,7L),
                  key="date")
dt2 <- data.table(date = as.Date("2015-06-30")+c(0:1,4L),
                  val = letters[7:9],
                  dummy = rep(NA,3),
                  key="date")
```

I want to have `val` column from `dt2` added to `dt1` using rolling join.
The following statement will produce similar output to the expected one:

```
dt2[dt1, roll=TRUE]
#          date val dummy
# 1: 2015-06-28  NA    NA
# 2: 2015-07-01   h    NA
# 3: 2015-07-03   h    NA
# 4: 2015-07-05   i    NA
```

The are two problems with that statement:
1. I didn't want to have `dummy` column
2. I want to do this by reference:

```
address(dt1)
# [1] "0x3b57540"
address(dt2[dt1, roll=TRUE])
# [1] "0x3b4e1f0"
```

So, I'm looking for rolling join and add column by reference for my `dt1` and `dt2`, expected output:

```
#          date val
# 1: 2015-06-28  NA
# 2: 2015-07-01   h
# 3: 2015-07-03   h
# 4: 2015-07-05   i
```

And of course `address(dt1)` should match to `address` of the *magic* statement.

Comment: surprised that `dt1[dt2,val:=i.val,roll=-Inf]` doesn't work (nor adding, e.g., `mult="all"` or `allow.cartesian=T`)... seems like a FR.

Comment: Are you looking for `dt1[, val := dt2[dt1, roll=TRUE]$val]` ? (This was mentioned by Arun in your github thread on this topic.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a method that should scale.

```
address(dt1)
# [1] "0x265a060"
ix = dt2[dt1, roll=TRUE, which=TRUE]
dt1[, val := dt2[ix, val]]
dt1
#          date val
# 1: 2015-06-28  NA
# 2: 2015-07-01   h
# 3: 2015-07-03   h
# 4: 2015-07-05   i
address(dt1)
# [1] "0x265a060"
```

Or without creating the index, directly as:

```
dt1[, val := dt2[dt1, val, roll = TRUE]] ## (1)
```

Note that this is more efficient than doing:

```
dt1[, val := dt2[dt1, roll = TRUE]$val] ## (2)
```

(2) performs the entire join (materialises all the columns) and then extracts `val`, where as (1) directly just extracts column `val`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround; not perfect because it still involves creating extra memory, though there may be a way to avoid this that's not coming to me right away (anyway the extra memory may be minimal):

```
> address(dt1)
[1] "0x57b5230"

rng<-range(dt1[,range(date)],dt2[,range(date)])

x<-data.table(date=seq(from=rng[1],to=rng[2],by="day"),
              key="date")

> address(x)
[1] "0x6aa2df0"

x[dt2,setdiff(names(dt2),"date"):=mget(setdiff(names(dt2),"date"))
  ][,val:=zoo::na.locf(val,na.rm=F)]

> address(x)
[1] "0x6aa2df0"

> dt1[x,val:=i.val][]
         date val
1: 2015-06-28  NA
2: 2015-07-01   h
3: 2015-07-03   h
4: 2015-07-05   i

> address(dt1)
[1] "0x57b5230"
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, cannot accept the answer as it isn't *by reference* - making copy means less scalable. And the focus of the question was on that particular solutions (rolling join and by reference) to have the most scalable solution. Also I think the `zoo::na.locf` can be much more expensive than data.table's rolling join.

Comment: There's no copy made--`x` is created with one column, then updated by reference. I agree it's likely slow, but the native way to do it should have been `dt1[dt2,val:=i.val,roll=-Inf]`, unless I'm missing something.